# Flutter - redirect to dial

Tags: flutter

How can we redirect the user from the app itself to the dial and also fill the dial by the persons number ?
for example if number = 073
then open the dial and fill it with 073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the url_launcher package to achieve this.

Install the package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)!, then the url to parse to dial a number will be "tel://{userPhoneNumber}"